# jQuery - one trigger 2 buttons with different outcome

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, triggers

I have the following situation see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rmt70fjw/

In this example there are 2 buttons where only **one** of them (`register-trigger`) triggers a popup to open. The other button `login-trigger` doesn't do this. This situation together with the HTML is a given, and cannot be changed. Be aware that the popup generator is more complex, than just the click on `hide` example here.

What I am trying to do is that `login-trigger` opens as well the popup via the `register-trigger` button and hides the registration form and shows the login form. And for the `register-trigger` button the other way around. Currently they arrive in a loop because of the popup trigger.

How do I do this? See fiddle with below jQuery attempt and problem.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.register-trigger').click(function(){
    jQuery('.popup').removeClass('hide');
});

jQuery('#close').click(function(){
    jQuery('.popup').addClass('hide');
});


// above is a given, cannot be changed

// below is the current attempt 

jQuery('.login-trigger, .register-trigger').click(function(e){
  if(e.currentTarget == '.register-trigger'){
    jQuery('.register-form').removeClass('hide');
    jQuery('.login-form').addClass('hide');
  } else {
    jQuery('.login-form').removeClass('hide');
    jQuery('.register-form').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('a.register-trigger').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Comment: `if ($(this).is(".register-trigger")) { $('.register-form').show(); $('.login-form').hide(); } else  { $('.register-form').hide(); $('.login-form').show(); }` and .register-trigger is already clicked so don't click it again

Comment: Or `if(e.currentTarget.className === 'register-trigger')`

Comment: @mplungjan I have tried this, but the `login-trigger` doesn't work. I think it's because of the `$('a.register-trigger').trigger('click');`

Comment: Why can't you change all code?

Comment: @mplungjan the popup is a generated plugin element. I'm trying to hook on that.

Comment: Sounds like you aught to remove that then and use a more sensible popup

Comment: @RajenderJoshi this doesn't cover the fact that `login-trigger` also needs to open the popup at the same time. Did you try this in the fiddle? It doesn't work.

Comment: @mplungjan yes, but that's not an option. This is why I am here to see if there is a solution to trigger the login button to open the popup including the forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add the `.register-trigger` class to your login button aswell in that case. That will trigger all events of your plugin on the login button click. If you then need some special logic like hiding the register form add some Event handler for your `login-trigger`

```js
$('.login-trigger').addClass('register-trigger');
// PLUGIN CODE START
jQuery('.register-trigger').click(function(){
 jQuery('.popup').removeClass('hide');
});

jQuery('#close').click(function(){
 jQuery('.popup').addClass('hide');
});

// PLUGIN CODE END



jQuery('.register-trigger').click(function(){
  jQuery('.register-form').removeClass('hide');
    jQuery('.login-form').addClass('hide');
});

jQuery('.login-trigger').click(function(e){
    jQuery('.login-form').removeClass('hide');
    jQuery('.register-form').addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
body { background-color: #ddd; }
p { width: 100%; }

.popup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 20%;
  width: auto;
  height: 66%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hide { display: none; }

form {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1.75rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

a:hover, #close:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="popup hide">
    <form class="login-form">
     <p style="padding:1rem 3rem;text-align:center;">This is the login form</p>
    </form>
    <form class="register-form">
      <p style="padding:1rem 3rem;text-align:center;">This is the registration form</p>
    </form>
    <div id="close">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <a class="register-trigger">Register</a>
    <a class="login-trigger">Log In</a>  
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this is a clever and working method. Thanks for understanding the scenario and giving a creative solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of jQuery which will work for you!

```
    jQuery('.register-trigger').click(function(){
        jQuery('.popup').removeClass('hide');
    });

    jQuery('#close').click(function(){
        jQuery('.popup').addClass('hide');
    });


    // above is a given, cannot be changed

    // below is to 

    jQuery('.login-trigger').click(function(e){
    jQuery('.popup').removeClass('hide');
        jQuery('.login-form').removeClass('hide');
        jQuery('.register-form').addClass('hide');
    });


    jQuery('.register-trigger').click(function(e){
        jQuery('.popup').removeClass('hide');
        jQuery('.register-form').removeClass('hide');
        jQuery('.login-form').addClass('hide');
    });
```

Comment: You edited the part which states `// above is a given, cannot be changed`. If this was the solution, I'd have done it. But the popup has one button attached and is plugin generated. Cannot change it. The main problem is that the '`login-trigger` button needs to trigger the register button as well.

Comment: It will work, you don't need to comment above code, You can Just add // below is to 

    jQuery('.login-trigger').click(function(e){
    jQuery('.popup').removeClass('hide');
        jQuery('.login-form').removeClass('hide');
        jQuery('.register-form').addClass('hide');
    });


    jQuery('.register-trigger').click(function(e){
        jQuery('.popup').removeClass('hide');
        jQuery('.register-form').removeClass('hide');
        jQuery('.login-form').addClass('hide');
    });

Comment: I see what you mean, but this is not the solution. Yes in this example it might be, but the popup generation is more complex than just the `hide` class.

Comment: Is it a secret ? We can only help you with the issue you post here and if that does not replicate your problem exactly it feels like a massive waste of time to even try tbh.

Comment: No, but I cannot add the entire JS code of the plugin popup here. The fact is that the popup pops up via the `register-trigger` only, the `login-trigger` needs to do the same thing via the other button. Please re-read the scenario. It's stated there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if i understood correctly, it should work like this. Alert should pop up with both buttons.

```
jQuery('.register-trigger').click(function(){
    jQuery('.popup').removeClass('hide');
});

jQuery('#close').click(function(){
    jQuery('.popup').addClass('hide');
});


// above is a given, cannot be changed

// below is to 

$('.login-trigger, .register-trigger').click(function(e){
    $('.popup').removeClass('hide');
  if(e.currentTarget == $('.register-trigger').get(0)){
    alert("test");
    $('.popup .register-form').removeClass('hide');
    $('.popup .login-form').addClass('hide');
  }
  else 
  {
    $(".register-trigger").trigger('click');
    $('.popup .login-form').removeClass('hide');
    $('.popup .register-form').addClass('hide');

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; the main problem is that the `login-trigger` also needs to trigger the popup via the `register-trigger` button. In this case the popup doesn't come up by clicking on `login-trigger`. But the popup trigger is in real scenario a plugin and a more complex trigger. So is it possible to also trigger the `register-trigger` with the `login-trigger`?